# Android: method call in an asyncTask response

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I get a network response in my android application with this listener:

```
  void getResponse(String id, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener);
```

in the fragment I am receiving this response and doing some bigger parsing action:

```
getResponse(id, response -> {
                   someBigParsingAction(response); 
                });
```

So my first question is this still asynchronous? 
I would say no, because I can't monitor some usage on other threads except the main thread.
 On which thread is this running?
And would it freeze my UI?

To add a second example:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
      someBigParsingAction(loadDownloadedData()); 
}
private void doOneThing() {}
}.execute();
```

Thank you 
smoo

Comment: could you post all the code.?

Comment: actually this is only  an idea and other code wouldn't be related to the questions. i will try to add another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read docs about `AsyncTask`. The only callback which running in WorkerThread is `doInBackground`. `onPreExecute` and onPostExecute running in UI thread. So the answer is no, your code is synchronous and it will block UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

For network calls I'll recommend using **okhttp** libarary. With okhttp you can do both **synchronous** and **asynchronous** network calls. By the way your AsyncTask example is doing all te work in main thread. Android's **AsyncTaks** is used for doing some work in background and reporting the result in the main thread. You must do the background work in **doInBackground**. AsyncTaks is doing his background work on executors. AsycTask has 2 executors **SerialExecutors** and **ThreadPoolExecutors**. Default AsyncTask executor is  **SerialExecutors**. You can do blocking network call in AsyncTask doInBackground but I don't recommend that because it is blocking all the other work that executor is going to post in that thread (even in ThreadPoolExecutor there will be a situation when all the thread will be busy and there will be some more work to do)